# Building and charging lithium-ion batteries safely and efficiently

Tags: lithium-ion

I have started a new venture, producing electric scooters, karts and trikes by converting salvaged materials and second hand bikes etc. These are all individual and build to order at this (very early) stage. So far I have mainly relied upon using existing motors, batteries and controllers and adapting them to suit various applications. I have experimented with rewinding a few motors to run on appropriate power sources with some success but I really want to start building decent batteries. Due mainly to cost, I have been using 5 no. 12 AH lead acid batteries but these are obviously less than ideal due to size and weight, not to mention poorer performance than lithium iron, for example, in terms of range.
I purchased a job lot of budget lithium iron batteries for tools, disassembled them and reconfigured them to produce a 60 volt pack.
The original product is 20/40 volt, 5.0/2.5 AH, comprising 10 no. Samsung 1865 cells and the necessary circuitry. the output is determined by the tool you connect it to (either 2 banks of 5 in parallel or 10 in series).
I have taken 9 units, soldered the terminals of each to provide 9 no. 20 volt, 5 AH units. Then I arranged 3 groups of 3 units (connected in series to provide 60 volts 5 AH each) and then connected the 3 no. 60 volt arrangements together in parallel to provide 60 volts 15 AH.
This seems to work a treat, it's a fraction of the weight of the lead acid and provides far better range, more than the 20% AH increase which I put down to the fact I'm not hauling the weight of the batteries themselves!!
Nothing seems to overheat or produce any signs of trouble but I'm not entirely confident that I'm not putting them under excessive load when I start the motor from standstill. I reckon I'm probably pulling 37 amps maximum so if anyone can advise on this, I'd be grateful.

My main question is regarding the charging of this battery pack. So far I have been using the specified battery tool charger to charge each unit separately but this is obviously a pain because it means messing around with all the connections and it takes around 35 minutes per unit. The charger's output is 21 volts at 4.0 amps.
I want to charge the whole pack at once so I have been experimenting with rewinding an old torroidial transformer from an amplifier. The plan is to step down the voltage and then rectify it but I know nothing about BMSs and I've read that these are crucial for charging lithium iron batteries. I have stripped off the existing secondary winding and figured out the turns per volt, as it was previously. I have a fairly good understanding of these things but I have been troubled by various conflicting advice on the internet. I know I can achieve the required voltage but I dont want to blast too much current into the thing, obviously. So I figured I would reduce the size of the wire in the secondary winding but I have also read things about weighing the wire and this is where my understanding expires!!  If I reduce the conductor size, will I cause problems? Will it overheat the transformer? Can I wind the of the appropriate weight and limit the current delivered to the rectifier??  Any advice or relevant calculation methods much appreciated.

But if anyone is more concerned with editing my spelling or grammar, please, dont waste your time! Thanks
'

Comment: No. You need to use a proper charger that operates in constant current mode and then switches to constant voltage mode at the appropriate time. You can't do this by setting the size of the wire. And it's "Lithium ion".

Comment: If you don't understand pack protection circuitry, charge profiles including relevant temperature modification, cell balancing, and charge termination you should find someone who does to help you, or spend the time to learn the subject well.  It's too big a subject for a simple question here, and lithium batteries can be very dangerous if not charged and handled properly.

Comment: Yeah, please read the two above comments carefully. Without a BMS to protect against over-discharge, the batteries will die quickly. Without an overcurrent protection they will explode if shorted. And charging without the proper care and balancing will either kill the batteries quickly or start a fire.  Note, IMR lithium cells have absolutely huge power capability which is awesome, but that tends to make "incidents" happen rather quickly. If it makes a funny noise, you have about one or two seconds.

Comment: ...and if you make a trike, for the love of your ass don't put the batteries right under the seat. These things turn into flamethrowers when they pop.

Answer (score 2):

> I know nothing about BMSs and I've read that these are crucial for
> charging lithium iron batteries.

A BMS usually provides 3 or 4 functions:-

1. Over-voltage protection on charge
2. Over-current and short-circuit protection
3. Under-voltage protection on discharge
4. Cell balancing (equalizes cell voltages at peak charge voltage)

Each of your units should have a built in circuit to at least protect it from over-charging. It *may* have cell balancing, and it may also have over discharge protection (though perhaps not if this is provided in the tool).

You could charge your battery with a power supply set to output a maximum of 63 V, current limited to 12 A. However each pack will have a slightly different capacity which may cause some to reach peak voltage (4.2 V per cell) before others. If this happens the pack that reaches peak voltage first will go over-voltage which should cause the protection circuit to cut out, preventing all the batteries from becoming fully charged.

Another problem with using a simple current-limited power supply is that won't cut off when the battery reaches full charge. You should have a circuit which detects when current drops to a low value (typically 1/10th the capacity = 1.5 A for you battery). Finally, your simple 'charger' won't detect overheating or low voltage (which requires charging at a low current until normal voltage is restored).

The capacity problem can be avoided by charging each unit separately occasionally to 'top balance' them, or you could make a circuit that balances the units automatically. If you wire them in groups of 3 in parallel and those 3 groups in series then only 3 balancing sections are required, but you will need to make a custom balancing circuit that limits voltage to 21 V per group.

The temperature of each unit could be monitored with a suitable circuit, which will have to take into account the different reference voltages in each parallel group (you could just ignore temperature, but realize that if a pack this size 'cooks off' it will cause serious damage!).

Answer (score 1):

For your questions about battery management systems I recommend the book by Micah Toll. It's a very good introduction to all the practicalities of using lithium batteries.

https://www.worldcat.org/title/diy-lithium-batteries-how-to-build-your-own-battery-packs/oclc/1154554444&referer=brief_results

For charging the batteries, have you considered using a switch-mode power supply instead of a transformer? They are generally more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted for this.  Summary answers from the engineers have been given, but if OP really wants to go ahead with making his own battery packs, there are enough hazards that reading an instructional book is really not a bad idea.  That said I have not read this book, I just looked at the chapter headings to make sure the right categories were there.

Comment: Very nice book. Thanks for sharing